# ConcurrentModificationException on list that is not being modified

Tags: java

Edit: Problem solved!

Thanks for the help everybody. I knew I needed to synchronise a set, just couldn't work out which one. Rather embarrassingly I had synchronised the the correct one but hadn't assigned the synchronised set to the variable. Oh well, we live and learn.

I'm relatively new to Java and this is my first solo project. I'm attempting to build a simple 2d platform game and am having a ConcurrentModificationException popup that I cannot figure out. I have searched for some time but cannot find anyone with a problem exactly like mine. The problem occurs in the following method:

```
public Set<Platform> change(Set<Platform> platforms)
{
    Set<Platform> viewSet = new HashSet<Platform>();
    Point abPos = ball.getAbPos();
    int viewWidth, viewHeight, viewXPos, viewYPos;
    for (Platform p : platforms) {
        if (null != p.getType()) {
            switch (p.getType()) {
                case PLATFORM:{
                    viewWidth = p.getWidth() * xRatio;
                    viewHeight = p.getHeight() * yRatio;
                    viewXPos = (p.getX() - ball.getX()) * xRatio + abPos.x;
                    viewYPos = (p.getY() - ball.getY()) * yRatio + abPos.y;
                    viewSet.add(new Platform(viewXPos, viewYPos, viewWidth, viewHeight, p.getType()));
                    break;
                }
                case WALL:{
                    viewWidth = p.getWidth() * xRatio;
                    viewHeight = p.getHeight() * yRatio;
                    viewXPos = (p.getX() - ball.getX()) * xRatio + abPos.x;
                    viewYPos = (p.getY() - ball.getY()) * yRatio + abPos.y;
                    viewSet.add(new Platform(viewXPos, viewYPos, viewWidth, viewHeight, p.getType()));
                    break;
                }
                case DROP:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
    return viewSet;
}
```

The method is called in the paintComponent() method of a JPanel and is from a Camera object I have created who's job is to take the list of objects passed to it by the method and resize them for drawing. This happens once in each iteration of the game. The list of objects passed to method are collected from a set distance to the player at each iteration and the returned list of resized objects are drawn by the paintComponent() method.

The problem is that often the change() method will throw a ConcurrentModificationException when I start a for loop to iterate through the list of objects passed to the method, although not on every iteration. I really can't work out why as the list throwing the exception is not modified in any way. Any help with this would be much appreciated as I'm starting to pull my hair out. I have tried synchronising various methods or collections but this does not seem to make any difference, apart from sometimes making the code lag.

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1429)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1453)
at mygame_2.Camera.change(Camera.java:39)
at mygame_2.Game2Window$DrawingPanel.paintComponent(Game2Window.java:237)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5217)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1042)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1975)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3912)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:842)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Apologies if the code or this question is messy.

Comment: `change` is called in AWT thread instead of program main thread. There may be a bad synchronziing issue. Simple anwser is to sychronize the set with `Collections.sychronizedSet()`.

Comment: Somewhere, the set that the variable `platforms` refers to is being modified while the `change` method is iterating over it; in code that you didn't show us. It might be happening on a different thread.

Comment: As previous commenters said, your input state was modified while `Camera.change` method iterated over it. There may however be another way of fixing it without using `synchronizedSet` as using it may result in slowdowns because it will create a queue of waiters to modify the collection, and may still cause a CME. You can try looking into `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet` class for your `platforms`

Comment: Using a `CopyOnWrite...` collections allows your iteration to continue even as the collection is modified elsewhere, but it has its costs. First, iteration will not "see" any updates that were done while it's in progress - you only see the set as it was right before you started iteration. Also, every update will effectively add another set internally, so additions may be slower and cost you memory.

Comment: I've solved the problem now, but just out of interest glee8e, the majority of my game code is in the extended JFrame class. Would it be better to put the code in the main class? At the moment all main does is create the game window and tell it to start running.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `viewSet` is local, so that one doesn't throw the exception, so eliminating the impossible, the only set that can throw this exception is the one you are passing in.

The `Set` you are passing in must be coming from somewhere, and something must be filling it.  Since `paintComponent` happens on the Swing rendering thread, the conflict could be that you are reading the `Set` on the Swing thread, while modifying it on another thread.

If you do your modification of this set inside a `synchronized` block and the traversing of the `Set` also in a `synchronized` block, the problem should disappear:

```
synchronized (set) {
    // read/write here
}
```

The variable `set` should be the same set in both cases.

Comment: Synchronizing on such set can mean, however, that updates of this set will always wait for iterations to finish - and, in fact, there is a possibility that one of these will never come through. There's no perfect answer to it that I know of, it depends on rest of the layout: how fast updates happen compared to iterations, is it okay for iteration to stop all updates, etc.

Comment: Well sure, but there is insuficient information to make that assesment.  The iteration looks fairly quick though (it is called from  `paintComponent` after all) so I think this simple approach will work here.  Using a concurrent collection seemed like overkill to suggest at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever gotten this error while using for-each loops. Try switching your for-each loop for a traditional for loop. It should get rid of the error.

Comment: Style of loop will not matter in this case, unless there are bugs with checks for concurrent modifications.